# Load CSS/JS only when that plugin is called in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have two plugin. The pseudo code is as below. I want to load CSS/JS only when that plugin is called.
Right now, all js/css from all the plugins are getting called. How do I prevent this ?

**Plugin 1**

```
class Plugin1 {

function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue')
}

function enqueue() {
  wp_register_style('xxx','path');
  wp_eneque_style('xxx);
 }
}
```

**Plugin 2**

```
class Plugin2 {

function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue')
}

function enqueue() {
  wp_register_style('xxx','path');
  wp_eneque_style('xxx);
 }
}
```

Comment: A plugin isn't *called*, it's either active or inactive. If the user disables your plugin, your enqueues aren't executed so the JS/CSS won't be added to the site. Once the plugin is enabled, they're always enqueued no matter what. If you want the user to switch that off even with your plugin enabled, you will have to implement an options page for your plugin offering a switch for JS/CSS on/off and enqueue those based on the option selected.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the name of plugin which will be in use when page is getting rendered ?